# VBA mismatch calculating days

Tags: vba, excel

In my excel spreadsheet my code had worked for about 2 months.  Now I get a Mismatch type 13 error when I run the code now.  Nothing has changed in the code.  My dates are in column J and K, the starting cell is #3 as the first two are headers. column L is blank and is the date is equal to 8 the cells change color to green and text is added "Emailed" also changing text color to white.  the other cells display the dates in a numeric value, I had made them inactive as I used them only to prove out formula.  Thank you for the help

```
Dim mydate1 As Date
Dim mydate2 As Long
Dim datetoday1 As Date
Dim datetoday2 As Long
Dim Lastrow As String

Dim x As Long

Lastrow = Sheets("TWO_List").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 3 To Lastrow 'Starting row

mydate1 = Cells(x, 11).Value ' TWO Required Completion Date
mydate2 = mydate1           'selects value to mydate2
'Cells(x, 41).Value = mydate2 'displays expire date

datetoday1 = Date               'sets date
datetoday2 = datetoday1         'selects todays date in datetoday2
'Cells(x, 42).Value = datetoday2 'display todays date

If mydate2 - datetoday2 = 8 Then 'Number of days email sent before TWO expired

    Cells(x, 12) = "Emailed" 'places Yes in Reminder cells
    Cells(x, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 10 'Color format
    Cells(x, 12).Font.ColorIndex = 2 'text color
    Cells(x, 12).Font.Bold = True 'Changes to bold text
```

Comment: most likely, if it has been working, the error is in the data, maybe one of your "dates" is actually text that looks like a date and not a true date.

Answer (score 1):

`Dim Lastrow As Long` Not As `String` and the dates should be declared as `Date` type.

Something like this works:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim mydate1 As Date
    Dim mydate2 As Date
    Dim datetoday1 As Date
    Dim datetoday2 As Long
    Dim Lastrow As String    
    Dim x As Long

    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 3 To Lastrow    
        mydate1 = Cells(x, 1).Value
        mydate2 = mydate1
        datetoday1 = Date
        datetoday2 = datetoday1

        If DateDiff("d", mydate2, datetoday2) = 8 Then
            Cells(x, 2) = "Emailed"
            Cells(x, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            Cells(x, 2).Font.ColorIndex = 2
            Cells(x, 2).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: if you are getting the mismatch then one of your dates are not a true date. @John

Comment: @John write `MsgBox mydate2 datetoday2` before the error and take a look at the `MsgBox`. As @Scott Craner said, most probably one of the date is not a valid one (e.g. 29/Feb/2018).

Comment: okay tried the above formula but it does not recognize expired dates in row k.

Comment: @John - how do these dates look like? Can you make a screenshot and put it the question?

Comment: @Vityata, I would add a picture if I could.  I would place the full excel file for review but I don't know how.

Comment: @John - just make a screenshot and insert it in the post.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay, had a project dumped on me with less than 24 hr notice.  I have found the issue and everything works correctly.  Thank you all for your help.  It was much appreciated!